# Is it correct to move the $\lim$ operator inside $\| \cdot \|$ in deriving this partial derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$, $F$ a Banach space, and $m \in \mathbb N^*$. Suppose $f:X \to F$ such that $\partial_{j_1} \cdots \partial_{j_{m+1}} f$ and $\partial^m f$ exist in a neighborhood of $a$ for all $j_1, \ldots, j_{m+1} \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. Assume $h^i = \left  (h_1^i, \ldots, h_n^i\right ) \in \mathbb R^n$ with $1 \le i \le m$.  We define a map $A$ by $$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
> A & {(\mathbb R^n)}^m
>  & \longrightarrow & F \\
>     & \left  [h^1, \ldots,h^m\right ] & \longmapsto & \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) \left  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}\right ) \end{array}$$

I have verified that $A$ is a multilinear map and thus $A \in \mathcal L^m(\mathbb R^n, F)$. Moreover, it follows from the definition of mixed partial derivative that $\partial^m f(a) \in L^m(\mathbb R^n, F)$. In the following, I try to prove that $$\partial_j (\partial^m f)(a) = A$$

I'm not sure if, in (5), I correctly move the lim operator inside the norm operator. Could you please verify if this step is correct? Thank you so much!

---

**My attempt:**

First, we have $$\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\partial^m f(a +te_j) - \partial^m f(a)}{t} \left  [h^1, \ldots,h^m\right ] - A \left  [h^1, \ldots,h^m\right ] \\
={}& \frac{\partial^m f(a +te_j)[h^1, \ldots,h^m] - \partial^m f(a) [h^1, \ldots,h^m]}{t}  - A [h^1, \ldots,h^m]\\
={}&  \frac{ \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) \left   (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}\right )-  \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)  \left  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}\right )}{t}  \\
& \quad - \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n  \partial_j \partial_{j_1} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)  \left  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}\right ) \\
={}&  \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \left (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m} \right) \cdot \left ( \frac{ \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) -\partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t}   -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) \right )
\end{aligned}$$

It follows that

$$\begin{aligned}
   & \lim_{t \to 0} \left \| \frac{\partial^m f(a +te_j) - \partial^m f(a)}{t} - A\right \| \\
\overset{(1)}{=}{}& \lim_{t \to 0} \sup_{\|h^1\|_1\le1,\ldots,\|h^m\|_1 \le 1} \left \|  \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n  \frac{\partial^m f(a +te_j) - \partial^m f(a)}{t} \left  [h^1, \ldots,h^m\right ] - A \left  [h^1, \ldots,h^m\right ] \right \|\\
\overset{(2)}{\le}{}& \lim_{t \to 0} \sup_{\|h^1\|_1\le 1,\ldots,\|h^m\|_1 \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \left |h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m} \right | \cdot\bigg \| \frac{ \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t}  \\
\overset{(3)}{\le}{}& \lim_{t \to 0} \sup_{\|h^1\|_1\le 1,\ldots,\|h^m\|_1 \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \|h^1\|_1 \cdots \|h^m\|_1  \cdot\bigg \| \frac{ \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t}  \\
&  \quad -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)\bigg \|\\
\overset{(4)}{\le}{}& \lim_{t \to 0}  \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \left \| \frac{ \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t} -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)\right \|\\
 ={}&  \color{blue}{\sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \lim_{t \to 0} \left \|  \frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t} -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)\right \|}\\
\overset{(5)}{=}{}&  \color{blue}{\sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \left \| \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t} -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)\right \|}\\
={}&   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \left \|  \partial_j \left ( \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f \right ) (a)  -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) \right \|\\
={}&   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \left \|  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)  -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) \right \|\\
={}&  0
\end{aligned}$$

$(1)$: This follows from the definition of the operator norm of a multilinear map.

$(2)$: This follows from triangle inequality.

$(3)$: It follows from the definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$ that $|h^1_j| \le \|h^1\|_1,\ldots, |h^m_j| \le \|h^m\|_1$ for all $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. As such, $\left |h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m} \right | =\left |h^1_{j_1}\right | \cdots \left | h^m_{j_m} \right | \le \|h^1\|_1 \cdots \|h^m\|_1$.

$(4)$: It follows from $\|h^1\|_1\le 1,\ldots,\|h^m\|_1 \le 1$ that $\|h^1\|_1 \cdots \|h^m\|_1 \le 1$.

Hence $$\partial_j (\partial^m f)(a) = A$$

Comment: This is correct because [the norm of any normed vector spaced is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369060/continuity-of-norm-need-to-understand-how-and-why).

Comment: Hi @MaximilianJanisch , I would like to confirm that even the map $$\frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t}$$ is not defined at $t=0$, we still have the equality [...]

Comment: [...] $$\lim_{t \to 0} \left \|  \frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t} -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)\right \| =  \left \| \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a + te_j) - \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a) }{t} -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (a)\right \|$$, right?

Comment: As long as the limit is well-defined there should be no problem

Comment: Thank you so much @MaximilianJanisch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maximilian Janisch confirmed that "As long as the limit is well-defined there should be no problem".

I post it as an answer to peacefully close this question.